# Only allow current date/time on SQL Server insertion

Tags: sql-server, default, check-constraints, getdate

I need a way to enforce a single value only within an inserted field, more precisely a DateTime field, that should always be set to the current date/time at insertion.
I am working on a university exercise and they want all the constraints to be done within the DB, ordinarily i would just put on a DEFAULT GetDate() and always use DEFAULT on inserts, but the exercise requirements prevent this.
Now for an integer i can do this(i've omitted the other fields, since they are irrelevant to the issue at hand) :

```
CREATE TABLE tester(
d INTEGER not null DEFAULT 3,
CONSTRAINT chkd CHECK(d = 3)
);
```

However what i want is the following :

```
CREATE TABLE tester(
d DATETIME not null DEFAULT GETDATE(),
CONSTRAINT chkd CHECK(d = ????????)
);
```

Re-iterating GetDate() in the check() will trigger an error on inserts, because the microseconds will cause a mismatch.
So i guess the first question is, is this possible? and if so(i hope so) how?

Comment: use a trigger to populate the field with the current time?

Comment: @RyanVincent Right thx, not sure why i didn't think of that, i use triggers elsewhere and it's really simple that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon Ryan's comment got to this answer which is working

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_date ON [dbo].[tester] 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE tester SET d = GETDATE() WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM INSERTED);
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't track the date/time in the `tester` table. Instead, have a separate table with a column that references the ID of the `tester` table as a foreign key constraint. The new table will have one other column, a `DateTime` column. On insertion into the `tester` table, a trigger can be fired that will insert a row into the new table containing the ID of the newly-created `tester` row as well as the current date/time.

Comment: Nice extension of Ryan's comment suggestion, although the separate table isn't necessary, can have the trigger act directly upon the tester table

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how much you needed to isolate that value and make sure users didn't have mechanisms by which they could change it and such.